# How to use a .cs.t4 file to generate code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates

I just got started on a project where the inicial programmer is no longer working with us. I found on the project some templates, like "`Controller.cs.t4`", but I don't know how to use them. I searched a bit on the web, and they don't seem to auto generate a .cs file like most T4 tutorials I saw online. How can I run it?

```
<#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension="cs" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ControllerName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ControllerRootName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="Namespace" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="AreaName" #>
<#
string routePrefix;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(AreaName)) 
{
    routePrefix = ControllerRootName;
}
else
{
    routePrefix = AreaName + "/" + ControllerRootName;
}
#>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace <#= Namespace #>
{
    public class <#= ControllerName #> : Controller
    {
        // GET: <#= routePrefix #>
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your t4 template has parameters, so it is being called from somewhere else. Look for ```.ProcessTemplate``` or ```ITextTemplating``` in your project.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like they are using a VS plugin thats unfortunately not supported any more